# Top 5 unique rows without Distinct from 7Million rows

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-optimization, distinct

Postgres 12 on GCP.
Table with approx 7-Million rows and growing.

```
select Distinct col1, col2
from tab_a
where col3='abc'
and col4='xyz'
order by col2
limit 5;
```

with Distinct this query take around 2.1 to 2.8 sec
without Distinct it took 0.25 sec, but my table got duplicate data as per business requirement.

Is there anyway I can get top 5 unique records without costly Distinct clause?
I can do following but its not the robust solution:

```
select Distinct 
col1, col2
from (
       select col1, col2
       from tab_a
       where col3='abc'
       and col4='xyz'
       order by col2
       limit 50
     )
limit 5;
```

Can someone guide me a more robust solution please?

Wishes

Comment: This time with the index or without the index on the table. Does the table have any index?

Comment: First a comment : in your initial query you limit to 5 resulting rows while ordering on col2 only, that means you get 5 rows with arbitrary col1 values as they are not ordered on col1. Then can you execute `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` on both queries with and without the `DISTINCT` clause ? Usually this is the `ORDER BY` clause which is costly.

Comment: You are not giving us enough information to pinpoint where the time is spent. 
You also give us an alternative version (albeit, as you say, not a robust one) but don't mention how much faster it is. Is there an index on tab a that handles `col3` and `col4`? Does it also include `col2` (and maybe `col1` ?)  How many rows are in the table that match the `WHERE` on `col3` and `col4`? How many distinct `col1` and `col2` do these have on average? etc etc...
As mentioned by @EdouardH. , please do run you queries with EXPLAIN ANALYZE so we have something to work with.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're using the same username as a [longtime contributor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name)  who often answers SQL questions. Maybe it would be wise for you to use another name.

Comment: sorry all for not giving full info
@O.Jones I have changed then name (thanks for telling me)

Details are as under:

index is there and query uses index.

1st query explain plan (with distinct)
https://ibb.co/DKyj1xn

1st query explain plan (without distinct)
https://ibb.co/3Tpq9zX

Can somehow I can compare output rows and keep getting rows till top unique 5 rows arrive without 'Distinct'? as in my case even top 100 return in millisecond without distinct

Answer (score 0):

SQL, especially for large tables, relies on indexes to run queries efficiently. You didn't tell us anything about your indexes, so there's some guessing in this answer.

[Creating the following index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createindex.html) should help your first query a lot. There's nothing wrong with that first query: if it meets your business requirements go ahead and use it.

```sql
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY tab_a_distinct 
                       ON tab_a USING BTREE
                          (col3, col4, col2, col1);
```

Why will this help?

1. BTREE indexes work as if they were sorted in the order of the items in the index.
2. You match for equality on `col3` and `col4` so postgreSQL can random-access the BTREE index to the first matching row, and then scan the index sequentially until it finds no more matching rows.
3. You want your output ordered by `col2`, so that column is next. postgreSQL will scan the index until it has the five rows you need then stop.
4. You want DISTINCT values of `col2` and `col3`. postgreSQL can get them from the index.

In other words, this is a *covering composite index* for your query.

Read this to learn more. https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: index is there and query uses index. 1st query explain plan (with distinct) ibb.co/DKyj1xn 1st query explain plan (without distinct) ibb.co/3Tpq9zX Can somehow I can compare output rows and keep getting rows till top unique 5 rows arrive without 'Distinct'? as in my case even top 100 return in millisecond without distinct